# Contributing to open source projects

Tags: c, open-source

I am relatively new to programming, but I enjoy it a lot. I was told that contributing to opensource projects is a good way to learn a lot more.  Anywyas, I was wondering if anybody knew what projects I could contribute to--even if I play a small role any experience would be appreciated.

My background is C and Java. I prefer working with C though.

Thanks!
Joey

Answer (score 4):

Well, probably you should contribute to a project you already *use*.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and look for a project you like. You'll be no use to anyone unless you have a personal interest in the software. Pick a project you use in your daily work and play and make it better. Start with a smaller project as you'll likely get a better reception than trying to work on Firefox or the Linux kernel.

Comment: How should i get it, by SVN? Then if i make some changes how can i commit, who decide my changes are friendly and good enough? Thanks